# how to allow a "?" in a .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been trying to figure out how to allow a question mark in a url with parameters using htaccess rewrite.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
https://website.com/auth?login=yes&redirecturl=www.google.com
```

keep in mind this is just an example of what i'm trying to accomplish.

here is the rewrite file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?key=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?key=$1
```

Thanks in advance for the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that you just want to keep GET parameters.

Take a look at this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Answer (score 0):

It need to be escaped: `index.php\?key=$1`

Answer (score 0):

You must use [Url Encode](http://php.net/urlencode)

So your "?" symbol should become %3F, a "&" should be %26, "\" -- %5C.